# return value of execute(command) when command has "silent!"

Tags: echo

In my understanding, the return value of `execute(command)` should be what `command` outputs. (The second parameter of `execute` is to affect whether this output will also be displayed in vim.)

Now `command` runs a function and inside the function there is `silent! echo 3`. so command itself does not have output. Shouldn't the result of `execute` be empty?

Ex:

```
function! s:x()
  silent! echo 3
endfunction
let x = execute('call s:x()') 
" let x = execute('call s:x()', '')  does not alter the output
" this means `call s:x()` itself has no output
echo 'x is' x
```

shows

```
x is
3
```

instead of

```
x is
```

**Is this a bug?** How to explain the phenomenon in the comment?

Comment: the minimal test is simply `:let x = execute('silent! echo 3')`

Comment: yes, looks indeed like a bug. Note however that this example is a bit silly.

Comment: Thank you @ChristianBrabandt. Do I need to create an issue in github?

Comment: yes, would probably be the best

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I have made a more realistic [example](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3659#issuecomment-445460921). Hope you will like it :)